# Can't easily access meta from main site

Tags: support, status-bydesign

How do I get to the meta portion of the site from the main site now? Other than following a link to a "FEATURED ON META" question there seems to be no link.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Stack Exchange logo on the top-right of each page has the same links to Meta and chat and other SE sites that used to be available from the SE logo on the top-left. (The top-left one, as you've probably noticed, now links to the SE homepage.)

[image: screenshot]